# Pop up modal is not working in a php output

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, filter

I have a pop-up model that works perfectly in my filter content page, the pop-up modal shows up when i click the button. However, after I filter the output, the pop-up model failed. Suppose i just copy and paste the HTML code to the PHP output, so I'm not sure which parts of it go wrong. Attached are the code in my PHP $output and you may try the pop-up model in https://gttutor.com/user-new-cases/. Thank you for your help!

```
<a><button class="btn popUpBtn" data-modal="aaa">Job!</button></a>
                                <div id="aaa" class="modal">
                                  <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                      <h2 class="poptitle">Case</h2>
                                      <span class="close">×</span>
                                    </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                                <form action="https://gttutor.com/" method= "post">
                                                        <label for="Selfintro">Self-intro:</label>
                            
                                                        <textarea id="Selfintro" name="Selfintro" value="" placeholder="" rows="4" cols="80"></textarea>
                            
                                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                                        <h3 class="cancel">Cancel</h3>
                                                        <input id="submit" class="savebutton" type="submit" value="Submit">
                                                    </div>
                                                </form>
                                        </div>   
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

```
    $('.popUpBtn').on('click', function(){
        $('#'+$(this).data('modal')).css('display','block');
    })


    $('span.close').on('click', function(){
        $('.modal').css('display','none');
    })
    
    $('h3.cancel').on('click', function(){
        $('.modal').css('display','none');
    })


    $(window).on('click', function(event){
        if (jQuery.inArray( event.target, $('.modal') ) != "-1") {
            $('.modal').css('display','none');
        }
    })
```

Comment: This seems like a JS/HTML question, not PHP. Your `id`s though appear to not be unique here, that could cause issues.

Comment: I have just changed all the id to unique one with an user id attached, but still doesn't work. I have just posted the script for your reference. THanks!